# Hibernate: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, servlets, hibernate-entitymanager

I was using Servlets, PostgreSQL and Hibernate with EntityManager to build a Web app and everything was working ok until I moved the project to a Maven based project. Now I'm getting this weird exception every time I try to create an EntityManager from an EntityManagerFactory :

```
org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.makePhysicalTransactionDelegate(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:229)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.getTransactionDriverControl(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.<init>(TransactionImpl.java:36)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getTransaction(AbstractSessionImpl.java:309)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:277)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1322)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.internalGetSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:174)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:83)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:311)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:278)
at cl.bicubic.App.getEntityManager(App.java:100)
at cl.bicubic.dao.DAO.<init>(DAO.java:24)
at cl.bicubic.dao.UserAtomicDAO.<init>(UserAtomicDAO.java:15)
at cl.bicubic.Application.init(Application.java:70)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the configuration of Hibernate in the persistance unit:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb?charSet=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.user" value="dbuser"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="dbpass"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
</properties>
```

This is how I create the EntityManagerFactory:

```
public class App {
    ...
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    ...
    public static void setServletContext(ServletContext context) throws IOException {
         ...
         entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit-name");
         ...
    }
    ...
    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(); //Here Throws the Exception
    }
    ...
}
```

I call this method using a ServletContextListener

```
@WebListener
public class ApplicationServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            App.setServletContext(sce.getServletContext());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(ApplicationServletContextListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

This is how I try to create the EntityManager

```
public class DAO {
    ...
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    ...
    public DAO() {
        entityManager = App.getEntityManager();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I have tried to look for more information about the origin of this JtaPlatformInaccessibleException, but I have found nothing. I'm not sure what's missing.

Comment: Im using Hibernate 5.0.1.Final and PostgreSQL driver 9.2-1002-jdbc4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ok...
this was just an error on the persistance unit xml configuration, I removed transaction-type="JTA" from the persistence-unit tag. It seems that it was added automatically by the IDE.

Comment: As per documentation, `JTA` is the default value for `transaction-type`. It should make no difference, whether you define it or leave it out completely.

Answer (score 18):

Just add the property to your persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. The original poster's solution did not work in my case. Using Hibernate 5.0.7 on Wildfly 10.0.0.Final, I needed the following lines in my persistence.xml:

<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">

...

<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />

Comment: this needs jndi lookup, if you are using embedded tomcat on container, this will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Transactional` to your DAO and the class accessing your DAO class.

Refer: http://spring.io/guides/gs/managing-transactions/

Comment: I'm not using Spring... just a simple HttpServlet. I tried to add the @Transactional and did nothing..

Comment: @Transactional is part of JPA javax.transaction.Transactional

Comment: Yeap I know... I added it.. and did nothing.