# Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

I'm trying to use JPA/Hibernate with Wildfly 10. I'm new to hibernate, so I'm in learning mode :-)

Below is my persistence.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="librarysoftjpa" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/PostGreLibrarySoftDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.models.Permission</class>
    <class>org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.models.Role</class>
    <class>org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.models.User</class>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Part of my Standalone.xml that defines the datasource:

```
 <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/PostGreLibrarySoftDS" pool-name="PostgrePool">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/librarysoft</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgres</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>test</user-name>
                        <password>test</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="postgres" module="org.postgres">
                        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

However, when I'm trying to access a webservice that calls the DB, I get:

```
  21:05:16,930 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: librarysoftjpa
    ...]
21:05:16,978 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment librarysoftbackend.war
21:05:17,137 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
21:05:17,152 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.10.Final}
21:05:17,154 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
21:05:17,157 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
21:05:17,230 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
21:05:17,733 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
21:05:18,217 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'librarysoftbackend.war#librarysoftjpa'
21:05:18,686 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
21:05:18,972 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
21:05:18,977 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4ab12ca3
21:05:18,984 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Envers integration enabled? : true
21:05:19,824 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
21:05:22,600 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.rest.RestApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
21:05:22,808 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /librarysoftbackend
21:05:22,869 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "librarysoftbackend.war" (runtime-name : "librarysoftbackend.war")
21:05:23,148 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
21:05:23,152 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
21:05:23,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 15007ms - Started 422 of 670 services (404 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
21:05:30,187 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) 0
21:05:30,306 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (default task-3) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: librarysoftjpa
    ...]
21:05:30,323 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
21:05:30,353 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl] (default task-3) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
21:05:30,361 INFO  [org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry] (default task-3) HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@4ab12ca3
21:05:30,365 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (default task-3) Envers integration enabled? : true
21:05:30,450 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (default task-3) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
21:05:30,671 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /librarysoftbackend/rest/users/all: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.makePhysicalTransactionDelegate(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.getTransactionDriverControl(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.<init>(TransactionImpl.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getTransaction(AbstractSessionImpl.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1327)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.internalGetSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:286)
    at org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.dao.HibernateUtil.getEntityManager(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.dao.UserDao.getAllUsers(UserDao.java:28)
    at org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.rest.UserWebService.getAllUsers(UserWebService.java:59)
    at org.declercq.librarysoftbackend.rest.UserWebService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getAllUsers(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
    ... 43 more
```

So this specifically is my problem:

```
21:05:30,671 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /librarysoftbackend/rest/users/all: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
```

I already checked this thread: [Hibernate: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505969/hibernate-unable-to-access-transactionmanager-or-usertransaction-to-make-physic).
However, this doesn't solve it for me. Anyone a suggestion on what I'm doing wrong here?

UPDATE1:
How I access my entitymanager:

I'm using this DAO class:

```
public class UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext (unitName="librarysoftjpa")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
List<User> allUsers=null;

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
        criteria.from(User.class);

        TypedQuery<User>query = entityManager.createQuery(criteria);
        allUsers = query.getResultList();
        return allUsers;    


    }
```

This is based on the User class:

```
@Entity (name="User")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {


    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String emailAddress;

    public User(String userName, String password, String emailAddress) {
        super();
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
........
```

So I changed some things.
First of all, added the transaction-type="jta" in my persistence.xml.
Also added org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider and removed some hibernate lines as suggested below.
Also, eliminated the hibernateutil class and now am using container managed persistence context by injecting it with @persistencecontext in my DAO class.

Nevertheless, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete the connection properties from the persistence.xml

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/librarysoft"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="test"/>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="test"/>
```

Second: how do you access the EntityManger?
You can inject it using the @PersistenceContext annotation.

The Java EE 7 Tutorial will be a good point to start:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/

Comment: Just updated my original post. I'm following the same concept as for a SessionFactory, by using a dedicated "HibernateUtil" class.

Comment: Just been reading up a bit on this topic. Am I correct in stating that, if I use transaction-type=jta in my persistence.xml, meaning that my persistence context is managed by the container, that I don't need to start, commit, ... transactions myself? The Container will do this automatically for me?

Comment: Yes, the container will take care of starting and committing all your transaction with JTA.